# Codenameone IOS app is crashing randomly

Tags: ios, crash, codenameone

Codenameone IOS app is crashing randomly. There is no exception/EDT error has been fired while running app. But it randomly crash and found below crash logs from device.

```
Incident Identifier: C682221D-9C59-42C9-B049-3E6356E47190
CrashReporter Key:   5904790c45bd8f37e39f83dc508ec9b515441f58
Hardware Model:      iPad4,2
Process:             Inspect [5399]
Path:                /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/650B079F-1AA2-435B-A617-F1AD99CF4E73/Inspect.app/Inspect
Identifier:          com.org.inspect
Version:             5.0 (5.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-07-29 11:43:04.04 +0530
Launch Time:         2016-07-29 11:41:59.59 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_RESOURCE
Exception Subtype: WAKEUPS
Exception Message: (Limit 150/sec) Observed 697/sec over 300 secs
Exception Note:  NON-FATAL CONDITION (this is NOT a crash)
Triggered by Thread:  3

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018322d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018322d338 mach_msg + 72
2   QuartzCore                      0x0000000185ef9058 _CASUpdateClient + 104
3   QuartzCore                      0x0000000185e000b8 CAImageQueuePing(_CAImageQueue*, bool) + 172
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000185dfffc8 CAImageQueueInsertImage_ + 432
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000185edc590 native_window_swap(_EAGLNativeWindowObject*, unsigned int) + 200
6   GLEngine                        0x000000019589f1fc gliPresentViewES_Exec + 200
7   GLEngine                        0x000000019589f0fc gliPresentViewES + 84
8   OpenGLES                        0x0000000185403cbc -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 72
9   Inspect                         0x000000010070e388 0x100090000 + 6808456
10  Inspect                         0x00000001000a0cc8 0x100090000 + 68808
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001830f95f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183108c5c _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 644
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001830f95f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001830fecf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018365cbb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018365aa18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183589680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
18  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184a98088 GSEventRunModal + 180
19  UIKit                           0x0000000188400d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
20  Inspect                         0x000000010070fca8 0x100090000 + 6814888
21  Inspect                         0x0000000100100278 0x100090000 + 459384
22  Inspect                         0x00000001002eea74 0x100090000 + 2484852
23  Inspect                         0x00000001006115bc 0x100090000 + 5772732
24  Inspect                         0x0000000100611618 0x100090000 + 5772824
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018312a8b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001832494fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018310c94c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001830fb7bc _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183248b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 Attributed:
0   Inspect                         0x0000000100096fc4 0x100090000 + 28612
1   Inspect                         0x0000000100152b34 0x100090000 + 797492
2   Inspect                         0x00000001007cb9ac 0x100090000 + 7584172
3   Inspect                         0x0000000100096a04 0x100090000 + 27140
4   Inspect                         0x00000001007acf24 0x100090000 + 7458596
5   Inspect                         0x00000001000fe8c4 0x100090000 + 452804
6   Inspect                         0x0000000100095704 0x100090000 + 22276
7   Inspect                         0x0000000100096ec4 0x100090000 + 28356
8   Inspect                         0x0000000100878e30 0x100090000 + 8293936
9   Inspect                         0x0000000100751954 0x100090000 + 7084372
10  Inspect                         0x0000000100752bf4 0x100090000 + 7089140
11  Inspect                         0x0000000100753b60 0x100090000 + 7093088
12  Inspect                         0x00000001008791b0 0x100090000 + 8294832
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fb28 _pthread_body + 156
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fa8c _pthread_body + 0
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018322d4f8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000018330697c _os_semaphore_wait + 24
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001831044ec _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 560
3   Inspect                         0x00000001000a12e8 0x100090000 + 70376
4   Inspect                         0x00000001007101e4 0x100090000 + 6816228
5   Inspect                         0x0000000100108000 0x100090000 + 491520
6   Inspect                         0x0000000100107e48 0x100090000 + 491080
7   Inspect                         0x00000001000c8a68 0x100090000 + 232040
8   Inspect                         0x00000001002f27c0 0x100090000 + 2500544
9   Inspect                         0x00000001002fd774 0x100090000 + 2545524
10  Inspect                         0x00000001002fde44 0x100090000 + 2547268
11  Inspect                         0x00000001005e2b54 0x100090000 + 5581652
12  Inspect                         0x00000001005217a4 0x100090000 + 4790180
13  Inspect                         0x00000001002641ec 0x100090000 + 1917420
14  Inspect                         0x00000001002646c0 0x100090000 + 1918656
15  Inspect                         0x00000001002654bc 0x100090000 + 1922236
16  Inspect                         0x000000010034520c 0x100090000 + 2839052
17  Inspect                         0x0000000100343ce4 0x100090000 + 2833636
18  Inspect                         0x0000000100294694 0x100090000 + 2115220
19  Inspect                         0x00000001002fc364 0x100090000 + 2540388
20  Inspect                         0x00000001002f24d0 0x100090000 + 2499792
21  Inspect                         0x00000001002f7080 0x100090000 + 2519168
22  Inspect                         0x000000010046d864 0x100090000 + 4053092
23  Inspect                         0x00000001000fdbf8 0x100090000 + 449528
24  Inspect                         0x0000000100753b60 0x100090000 + 7093088
25  Inspect                         0x00000001008791b0 0x100090000 + 8294832
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fb28 _pthread_body + 156
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fa8c _pthread_body + 0
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183247f48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330ece8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   Inspect                         0x000000010087898c 0x100090000 + 8292748
3   Inspect                         0x000000010073fb40 0x100090000 + 7011136
4   Inspect                         0x000000010073fa14 0x100090000 + 7010836
5   Inspect                         0x000000010046de9c 0x100090000 + 4054684
6   Inspect                         0x00000001000fdbf8 0x100090000 + 449528
7   Inspect                         0x0000000100753b60 0x100090000 + 7093088
8   Inspect                         0x00000001008791b0 0x100090000 + 8294832
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fb28 _pthread_body + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fa8c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183248440 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018316522c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018316514c usleep + 68
3   Inspect                         0x0000000100097498 0x100090000 + 29848
4   Inspect                         0x0000000100097d20 0x100090000 + 32032
5   Inspect                         0x0000000100877970 0x100090000 + 8288624
6   Inspect                         0x00000001007445e4 0x100090000 + 7030244
7   Inspect                         0x000000010072dc64 0x100090000 + 6937700
8   Inspect                         0x0000000100731914 0x100090000 + 6953236
9   Inspect                         0x0000000100573518 0x100090000 + 5125400
10  Inspect                         0x0000000100573efc 0x100090000 + 5127932
11  Inspect                         0x0000000100573efc 0x100090000 + 5127932
12  Inspect                         0x0000000100573efc 0x100090000 + 5127932
13  Inspect                         0x0000000100573efc 0x100090000 + 5127932
14  Inspect                         0x0000000100572e10 0x100090000 + 5123600
15  Inspect                         0x00000001006f3ea0 0x100090000 + 6700704
16  Inspect                         0x00000001005a1b34 0x100090000 + 5315380
17  Inspect                         0x00000001005adf08 0x100090000 + 5365512
18  Inspect                         0x00000001005e2ecc 0x100090000 + 5582540
19  Inspect                         0x000000010046d7f4 0x100090000 + 4052980
20  Inspect                         0x000000010046e06c 0x100090000 + 4055148
21  Inspect                         0x00000001000fdbf8 0x100090000 + 449528
22  Inspect                         0x0000000100753b60 0x100090000 + 7093088
23  Inspect                         0x00000001008791b0 0x100090000 + 8294832
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fb28 _pthread_body + 156
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330fa8c _pthread_body + 0
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183248b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018330d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000012d6b87c0   x1: 0x00000001318ae8e0   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x0000000100152b10
    x4: 0x000000000000031b   x5: 0x000000000000032a   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x000000000beba6a8
    x8: 0x0000000100c5b9f8   x9: 0x0000000100c5a0e0  x10: 0x0000000000000284  x11: 0x0000000000000283
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x000000000609eb00  x14: 0x0000000100000000  x15: 0x000000016e1ba9d0
   x16: 0x000000018330d64c  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000001
   x20: 0x0000000130516730  x21: 0x000000012d6b87c0  x22: 0x0000000100c39000  x23: 0x00000000000001b2
   x24: 0x000000012d8d7c40  x25: 0x0000000100c5a0e0  x26: 0x0000000100c3a000  x27: 0x0000000000000b40
   x28: 0x0000000100c5a0e0  fp: 0x000000016e1ba6e0   lr: 0x0000000100152b34
    sp: 0x000000016e1ba6c0   pc: 0x0000000100096fc4 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

I guess this crash happened only when i am trying to save lots of data into xml.Below is the code glimpse for your reference.It never failed with 300-400 fields of data.

```
    XMLParser xp = new XMLParser();
    XMLWriter xw = new XMLWriter(true);
    SecurityUtil securityUtil = new SecurityUtil();

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        if(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(filePath)){

            is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(filePath);
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(securityUtil.decrypt(FileUtil.convertToByteArray(is,length)));
            Reader isReader = new InputStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream,"UTF-8");

            //Get parent element from xml file
            final Element response = xp.parse(isReader);

            if(response!=null){
                //Approx 700 - 1500 list data to be saved
                for (final FormData fromDataObj : listInputs) {

                //Set values to the appropriate field
                response.getElementById(fromDataObj.getInputId()).setAttribute(Constants.FIELD_ATT_VALUE, fromDataObj.getInputValue());
                }
            }

            //write back element into xml file

            OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(filePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(bo,"UTF-8");
            xw.writeXML(ow, response);
            ow.close();
            os.write(securityUtil.encrypt(bo.toByteArray()));
            os.close();
            bo.close();
            bo = null;
            os = null;

            }

            if(byteArrayInputStream!=null){
                byteArrayInputStream.close();
                byteArrayInputStream= null;
            }
            if(isReader!=null){
                isReader.close();
                isReader= null;
            }

        }

        if(is!=null){
            is.close();is=null;
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            if (is != null) {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            is = null;
        }
        throw e;
    }
```

Anybody face such issue before and solved?

Any suggestion will be most appreciate.

Comment: It was suggested before so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't the cause of the crashes see the comment within the log. Also refer to [this old issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1372).

You need to narrow down the crash test case.

Comment: @Shai-Thanks for suggestion.Actually this is totally unrelated to my issue. Mostly it crashed at the time of saving 700 to 1500  values in XML.Code pattern I have just edited in the call.Please check.

Comment: It sounds like an out of memory crash. Try moving all the parsing code to a different method so it goes out of scope and can get GC'd (the reader, input stream, byte array input etc.) then you will be left only with the parsed data in RAM.  Then move the conversion to byte array into a separate method too so the byte array output stream and all related code can be gc'd.

Comment: @Shai-Could you please give some hint code method?  I have already added above code in separate method and call that method while click on save action.

Comment: I suggest using a profiler for memory and analyzing where GC resources are released. I suggest scoping the method to smallest bits possible and passing the least amount of references. If you still get a crash look at the crash file and see if it's due to memory or something else

Comment: @Shai-I have added read from xml and write xml code in different method and it works fine.